# How to use a table to translate values?

Tags: c#

I have a reference table with two columns, one contains a char and the other an integer. Like this:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| ... | ... |
| : | 42 |
| / | 43 |

I also have a string of text as aninput for my program. Like "Hello world".

What I want to do is for each character of my input string obtain its integer representation (according to the table). How can I efficiently store and acces this table?

I thought about manually creating a dictionary, but then where should I store this for convenience ?

Or maybe load the data from a file every time the application starts, but that doesn't sound too efficient...

Comment: *"I thought about manually creating a dictionary, but then where should I store this for convenience ?"*. That depends on where it's used. There's no point having a global variable that is used in one place in your code. It's going to take a matter of milliseconds to generate that `Dictionary` even if it's quite big. Don't waste time micro-optimising your code.

Comment: @Valenj10 Put the data in a SQLite Database then you will learn something of great value and it will make the process easy You can find a lot of SQLite DB code builds here

Comment: Is the column on the right always going from 1 to n without a gap?

Comment: @NineBerry yes, no gaps

Comment: Then you can just use a string literal with the characters in the correct order and use IndexOf to get the integer position within the string.

Comment: @NineBerry oh right I hadn't thought about that, I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a dictionary which you can then access everytime you need it. A dictionary is a class that exactly handles what you need, you basically bind a key to a value (in a similar way to the KeyValuPair class) and you can then input a key and you'll receive the value of such key if it exist.

Creating a dictionary is very easy, you can do it like this

```
Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();
for(int i = 0; i < Table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dict.Add((char)Table.Rows[i]["charColumn"], (int)Table.Rows[i]["intColumn"]);
}
```

Then you can access that dictionary anytime you need it, also it's extremely fast to generate and to access. It's faster than having to create a query each time (this, of course, only if the data is static, if the value for each key can change over the course of a run time of your program you'll need to use a query each time)

To find a value for a key you can do

```
int value = dict["keyValue"];
```

Doing so is not totally good, because if you don't find the key you will get and exception. You should use a try-catch construct

For more info about it check the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0)